# Footnotes not displayed with showexpl

Tags: footnotes, showexpl

The following LaTeX document:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{showexpl}
\begin{document}

\begin{LTXexample}
  \documentclass{amsart}
  \begin{document}
      Hello\footnote{Hola}, world!
  \end{document}
\end{LTXexample}

\end{document}
```

results in the following pdf output:

[image: pdf corresponding to LaTex code]

Why is the footnote not displayed? What needs to be changed so the footnote gets displayed?

Comment: may I know why do you need the `\begin{LTXexample}...\end{LTXexample}` Without that, I get the footnotes working fine.

Comment: @RaajaG: This question was intended for people who are familiar with the `showexpl` package.

Comment: showexpl redefines a few commands to do nothing; beside others like \documentclass  and \usepackage also \footnote. One could change the output, but it is quite unclear what you actually expect to happen -- after all the footnote text is normally quite far away. Imho it would be better to prepare a suitable graphics and to load this.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: You wrote: "it is quite unclear what you actually expect to happen -- after all the footnote text is normally quite far away." In a different thread [you suggested](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/371218/how-to-add-vertical-space-between-a-showexpl-ltxexample-environment-and-the-surr#comment917312_371218) that I check out the `tcolorbox` package. As it turns out, the `tcolorbox` package understands what I expected to happen quite readily, and renders it correctly.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Indeed, if you create a minimal LaTeX document, load the `tcolorcbox` package by inserting `\usepackage[listings]{tcolorbox}` in the preamble, write the following in the body: `\begin{tcblisting}{}Hello\footnote{Hola}, world!\end{tcblisting}`, and then compile the document to typeset it as a pdf file, the result is precisely what I expected to happen when I wrote the present post.