# How to add vertical space between a showexpl/LTXexample environment and the surrounding text as well as the caption?

Tags: spacing, graphics, listings, showexpl

The following LaTeX document:

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{showexpl}

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ut ius vero dolores.

\begin{LTXexample}[caption=Example]
\documentclass{amsart}
\begin{document}
    Hello, world!
\end{document}
\end{LTXexample}

Te tollit ignota suscipit eum, id omnes corrumpit deseruisse duo, oblique recusabo qui eu.

\end{document}
```

results in the following pdf rendering:

[image: pdf rendering of the above LaTeX code]

How can I add space (1) above and (2) below the listing caption as well as (3) between the listing and the following paragraph?

---

**My attempted solution**

According to [the `showexpl` package's user manual](http://ftp.cc.uoc.gr/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/showexpl/doc/showexpl.pdf) (under section 2 'Usage' on p. 1)

> `showexpl` doesn't know any options by itself, but all options for the underlying packages (`listings` and `graphicx`) will be passed to the respective packages.

According to [the `listings` package's user manual](http://ftp.ntua.gr/mirror/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf) (under section 2.7 'Layout elements', paragraph 'Vertical space' on p. 16)

> The keys `aboveskip` and `belowskip` control the vertical space
>   above and below displayed listings.

Therefore, I tried adding `aboveskip=25pt`, respectively `belowskip=25pt`, as options to the `LTXexample` environment.

The `aboveskip` option added space below the caption, but the output was no longer vertically centered with respect to the code:

[image: Result of adding the aboveskip option]

On the other hand, the `belowskip` option caused the LaTeX compiler to fail with the following error message:

```
ERROR: Missing number, treated as zero.

--- TeX said ---  
<to be read again> 
                   \let  
l.14 \end{LTXexample}

--- HELP ---
This is usually caused by a LaTeX command expecting but not finding either a number
or a length as an argument. You may have omitted an argument, or a square bracket
in the text may have been mistaken for the beginning of an optional argument. This
error is also caused by putting \protect in front of either a length command or a
command such as \value that produces a number.
```

Comment: Your output consists of two parts: the listing and the output, and showexpl puts them side-by-side. So keys to change the spacing of the listing are only in part relevant. I would suggest that you use instead of showexpl `tcolorbox` and its listing library. Much more powerful ... (and better documentated).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Thanks. `tcolorbox` looks amazing. Exactly what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Ulrike Fischer [suggested](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/371218/how-to-add-vertical-space-between-a-showexpl-ltxexample-environment-and-the-surr/376398?noredirect=1#comment917312_371218), the best practical way to solve my problem is to dump the `showexpl` package in favor of the amazingly versatile and infinitely customizable [`tcolorbox` package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox?lang=en).

Comment: If you post a minimum working example and an image of how to do it, you will get more votes.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes: I haven't actually used it yet, just browsed through the manual.

Answer (score 1):

Here I rely on `\addstackgap[<length>]{}` from the `stackengine` package to provide the gap.  However, the quirk here is that the `LTXexample` cannot go into an `\hbox`, but only a `\vbox`.  So I save it in a temporary `\box0` and then use `\makebox` to set `\box0` in a full width box, to which I can add the stacking gap, shown here twice, once with 5pt and then with 25pt gap.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{showexpl,stackengine}
\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ut ius vero dolores.

\setbox0=\vbox{
\begin{LTXexample}[caption=Example]
\documentclass{amsart}
\begin{document}
    Hello, world!
\end{document}
\end{LTXexample}
}
\noindent\addstackgap[5pt]{\makebox[\textwidth]{\box0}}
Te tollit ignota suscipit eum, id omnes corrumpit deseruisse duo, oblique recusabo qui eu.

\setbox0=\vbox{
\begin{LTXexample}[caption=Example]
\documentclass{amsart}
\begin{document}
    Hello, world!
\end{document}
\end{LTXexample}
}
\noindent\addstackgap[25pt]{\makebox[\textwidth]{\box0}}
Te tollit ignota suscipit eum, id omnes corrumpit deseruisse duo, oblique recusabo qui eu.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Your solution only addresses points 1 (space above listing) and 3 (space below listing) in my question but not 2 (space below listing's caption), correct?

Comment: @EvanAad That is correct.  I think something different will be needed for the last point.  I'm giving it some more thought.

Comment: Thanks, though I wouldn't sweat over it, unless the challenge gives you a kick, because there is a *way* superior solution in the form of the `tcolorbox` package, as suggested by Ulrike Fischer in his comment to my question.

Comment: @EvanAad FYI, Ulrike is a "she".

Comment: @EvanAad  Perhaps, since Ulrike failed to post an answer, you could post the `tcolorbox` answer and accept it as the best answer.