# Emergency stop trying to base a new environment on the showexpl/LTXexample environment

Tags: errors, environments, showexpl

Yesterday I posted [a question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/371218/how-to-add-vertical-space-between-a-showexpl-ltxexample-environment-and-the-surr) asking how to apply certain formatting features to the environment `LTXexample` of the package `showexpl`. Seeing as the question failed to elicit answers, I tried to attack the problem from a different direction, by defining a custom environment that would wrap around `LTXexample` and provide the extra desired formatting. Never having defined a custom environment before, I started from the simplest possible first draft: creating a plain alias for 'LTXexample', as follows.

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{showexpl}

\newenvironment{lx}
    {\begin{LTXexample}}
    {\end{LTXexample}}

\begin{document}

\begin{lx}
Hello, world!
\end{lx}

\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, running the above LaTeX file through the LaTeX compiler resulted in the following error message.

```
ERROR: Emergency stop.

--- TeX said ---
! Emergency stop.
--- HELP ---
No help available
```

However, the file that is obtained by replacing the last two occurrences of the string 'lx' with 'LTEexample' compiles smoothly.

Comment: like any verbatim environment, you can not nest in that way. after the start of the environent `\ ` no longer is the escape character so `\end{lx}` is just a string to be typeset not the end of the environment, verbatim environments have to look for their end marker explictly and in this case it's looking for `\end{LTXexample}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I based my attempted solution on [this](http://imgur.com/a/O6cU0) (from George Grätzer's book 'More Math Into LaTeX', 5th edition (Springer 2016), p. 380). How should I fix my code?

Comment: That is completely different as it is not a verbatim environment that turns off normal processing.  You can not use `\verb` in the argument of another command and you can not nest verbatim environments in the definition of another environment.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle So is there no way of defining a new environment to wrap around `LTXexample`?

Comment: well of course there is always a way, `showexpl` doesn't have magical properties, if it can define an environment with verbatim properties, so can anyone else, but the default position should be that it's not possible and you should consider if it's needed before doing it. That said it is just defined using the `listings` package which offers a  definition command for verbatim environments `\lstnewenvironment{LTXexample}[1....`  so you could just copy that and adapt...